# Why i can't get profile image in 'SettingActivity'?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to upload my profile picture, also I get the message of the profile picture is been successfully upload but not able to see it in setting activity

I tried to change the firebase account but not able to work.
when I select photo it takes me to my internal storage, when I select the image it again takes me to choose section of photo uploading ways such as album, google photos internal storage, download etc. when the photo is been uploaded it is been showing in the firebase storage section but it is not showing in the app.
here is the [code link](https://github.com/sadsouler/Chat)

````
        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name") && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")))) {
                            String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveUserStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                            userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                            userStatus.setText(retrieveUserStatus);
                            Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);

                        }
                        else if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name"))) {
                            String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveUserStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                            userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                            userStatus.setText(retrieveUserStatus);
                        }
                        else {
                            userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Check The Details Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private void UpdateSettings() {
        String setUserName = userName.getText().toString();
        String setStatus = userStatus.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserName)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "UserName is Empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setStatus)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Status is Empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            HashMap<String, String> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
                profileMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
                profileMap.put("name", setUserName);
                profileMap.put("status", setStatus);
            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).setValue(profileMap)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                SendUserToMainActivity();
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Updates. Thank You!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Can you post one of the user data from database? So we can identify which value there is in database stored with "image" key.

Comment: ya sure I will send the screenshot of the database where the image is been uploaded

Comment: here is the link [image](https://imgur.com/a/YlZhOmY)

Comment: By the way, I have asked for your data structure. Not your image storage.

Comment: where can I find it by the way im new to android I'm making this app by seeing video tutorials

Comment: Okay. forget that. Just let me know which data you are getting as user image on launch of setting activity. You should need to use debug point inside `RetrieveUserInfo` method at some line in `onDataChange.

Comment: username, profile image and Department this 3 only after registering for the first time and the user can also change from main activity by going into the menu and then account settings

Comment: You didn't get me. I want to check the data which you are storing in database.

Comment: here is the link https://imgur.com/j2UUb5c and both the rules are been true

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to send image from your app.
In `UpdateSettings()` method you have to send image to firebase.
In below HashMap add image and send to firebase,

```
HashMap<String, String> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
profileMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
profileMap.put("name", setUserName);
profileMap.put("status", setStatus);
profileMap.put("image", [YOUR_IMAGE_STRING]);
```

Comment: I just made a few changes in Setting Activity and it is working now thank you guys for your help hope you all will help me in future project.